# Can you create multiple instances of a class using method injection or some other form of injection?

Tags: methods, ninject, code-injection

```
public interface IFoo {}

public class Foo : IFoo {}

public sealed class NinjaModule : NinjectModule //Appropriately configured in project
{
    public override void Load()
    {
        Bind<IFoo>.To<Foo>.InTransientScope();
    }
}

public class SomeOtherClass : ISomeOtherInterface
{
    public SomeOtherClass();

    public IFoo GetFoo(IFoo foo)
    {
        return foo;
    }

    public void GetFoos()
    {
        foreach (var thing in everything)
        {
            var localFoo = GetFoo();
            localFoo.UniqueProperty = "I am unique";
            _fooList.Add(localFoo);
        }
    }
}
```

I need my code to look something like that.

Yes, I am fairly new to inject. I am fairly certain that I am missing a basic principle.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: What's the purpose of the foreach loop? You create several IFoo instances and put them to a list. But the entries of everything seem not to be used. Or you simplified your code too much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the best approach here would be to use a factory to create the different Foo instances. And with Ninject and the Factory extension that's pretty easy.

```
public sealed class NinjaModule : NinjectModule //Appropriately configured in project
{
    public override void Load()
    {
        Bind<IFoo>().To<Foo>().InTransientScope();
        Bind<IFooFactory>().ToFactory();
    }
}

public interface IFooFactory
{
   IFoo CreateFoo();
}


public class SomeOtherClass : ISomeOtherInterface
{
    private IFooFactory fooFactory;

    public SomeOtherClass(IFooFactory fooFactory)
    {
        this.fooFactory = fooFactory;
    }

    public IFoo GetFoo(IFoo foo)
    {
        return this.fooFactory.CreateFoo();
    }

    public void GetFoos()
    {
        foreach (var thing in everything)
        {
            var localFoo = GetFoo();
            localFoo.UniqueProperty = "I am unique";
            _fooList.Add(localFoo);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This was a bad question. I figured out this needed to be implemented higher up by the class controlling these implementations.

Answer (score 0):

This was a bad question. I figured out this needed to be implemented higher up by the class controlling these implementations.